# Ruby parsing parsed response

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

First time messing with ruby.

The library I am using has this

```
require 'net/http/post/multipart'
require 'uri'

    def find(issue_id)
      get("issue/#{issue_id}")
      response.parsed_response
    end
```

and I used it in my file as

```
puts issue_resource.find("XVRCI-42")
```

which prints

**{"issue"=>{"field"=>[{"value"=>"XVRCI", "type"=>"SingleField", "name"=>"projectShortName"}, {"value"=>"42", "type"=>"SingleField", "name"=>"numberInProject"}, {"value"=>"Add CHANGELOG.MD with Short Changelog Generation Script", "type"=>"SingleField", "name"=>"summary"}, {"value"=>"We need a changelog at root and a script that generates a short changelog when we push out now XVRClient Harnesses and new releases.", "type"=>"SingleField", "name"=>"description"} etc...}], "id"=>"XVRCI-42", "entityId"=>"66-4857"}}**

I assumed this is json and parsed.
So I tried to add `require 'json'` and run

```
respons = JSON.parse(issue_resource.find("XVRCI-42"))
puts respons["field"][0]["name"]
```

it didnt work

How can I get summary field here and obtain the "Add CHANGELOG.MD with Short Changelog Generation Script" in a string variable?

######## EDIT ANSWER

thanks to martin turns out it is hash

so

```
#get the summary field
file['issue']['field'].each do |item|
   if item['name'] == "summary"
     puts item['value']
  end
end
```

worked for me

Comment: It does not look like json - the => symbol is more like the ruby one for a hash. Could you give me the result of: puts issue_resource.find("XVRCI-42").class ?

Comment: @Martin yes you are right, it printed `Hash`

Comment: @u.gen just to point out, you'd want a ``break`` after you find the item as it will loop till the end otherwise (i.e. ``file['issue']['field'].each do |item| break puts item['value'] if item['name'] == 'summary' end``)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Please use proper formatting as it helps us help you, along with those who in the future are looking for similar solutions. Please don't add solutions to your question. If you found an answer on your own you should add that as an answer, but if someone else provided the answer then selecting it is the proper response. Stack Overflow is a reference book in the making, so concise questions and answers are the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your source, what you need is:

```
puts respons["issue"]["field"][0]["name"]
```

Comment: I will try this , but is there a way to check name equals to summary rather than get the first element here [0] , I dont wanna rely on that if the order changes

Answer (score 1):

[Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) is what you want here.

```
response['issue']['field'].find {|x| x['name'] == 'summary'}
=> {"value"=>"Add CHANGELOG.MD with Short Changelog Generation Script", "type"=>"SingleField", "name"=>"summary"}
```